# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to resolve DirectoryNotFoundException: Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, I am saving a `.pdf` file into a directory, and then other parts into the database.

The solution is shown below:

```
MySolution
|- Application (Class Library - references Core)
    |-Services
|- Core (Class Library referenced by Application)
|- WebApi (Web API - references Application)
    |-Controllers
    |-Resources\FileAttachments 
    |-Program.cs
```

It goes this way:

```
Core -> Application -> Web API
```

In the Web API, I have the directory for the attached file (`Resources -> FileAttachments`).

Then I have the code in the application:

Services:

```
public async Task<Response<AllApprovedListDto>> DocApprovalBy(Guid id, ApprovalDto model)
{
    var myFiles = _unitOfWork.AdminFiles.GetById(id);
    var response = new Response<AllApprovedListDto>();

    if (myFiles != null)
    {
        try
        {
                List<IFormFile> attachments = new List<IFormFile>();

                foreach (var attachment in attachments)
                {
                    if (ConstantHelper.CheckIfPdfFile(attachment))
                    {
                        ApprovalAttachment approvalAttachment = new ApprovalAttachment();
                        var filePath = Path.Combine(@"Resources", DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff"), @"FileAttachments", attachment.FileName);
                        var fileExtension = "." + attachment.FileName.Split('.')[attachment.FileName.Split('.').Length - 1];
                        new FileInfo(filePath).Directory?.Create();

                        await using var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
                        await attachment.CopyToAsync(stream);

                        approvalAttachment.FileType = fileExtension;
                        approvalAttachment.FileName = attachment.FileName;
                        approvalAttachment.FilePath = filePath;
                        approvalAttachment.ApprovalId = model.Id;

                        // Insert attachment data into the DB
                        await _unitOfWork.ApprovalAttachments.InsertAsync(fileAttachment);
                        await _unitOfWork.Save();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _logger.Information("Invalid File Extension! Kindly attach PDF File");
                        response.Data = null;
                        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                        response.Message = "Invalid File Extension! Kindly attach PDF File";
                        response.Successful = false;
                        return response;
                    }
                }

                response.Message = "Successfully Approved Mandate";
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                response.Successful = true;
                response.Data = _mapper.Map<AllApprovedListDto>(model);
                return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error("An error occurred: " + ex);
            response.Message = "An error occurred";
            response.Successful = false;
            response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return response;
        }
    }

    return response;
}
```

Program.cs:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Resources")),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/Resources")
});
```

When I deployed the project in IIS and wanted to access it, I got this error:

> DirectoryNotFoundException: E:\myapp\Resources\
>
> Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(string root, ExclusionFilters filters)
> Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(string root)
> Program.$(string[] args) in Program.cs
> Program.(string[] args)

In the deployed project I created a `Resources` folder, and inside it `FileAttachments`, then granted permission.

However, the error still persists.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [IWebHostEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostenvironment?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to get the file path instead of `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`.

**How to use it?**

You will need to import the following namespace.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
```

In the below example, the `IWebHostEnvironment` is injected in the Controller and assigned to the private property Environment and later used to get the `WebRootPath` and `ContentRootPath`.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IWebHostEnvironment _environment;
 
    public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment Environment)
    {
          _environment = Environment;
    }
 
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        string wwwPath = this.Environment.WebRootPath;
        string contentPath = this.Environment.ContentRootPath;
 
        return View();
    }
}
```

In your project, You just need to use:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath,"Resources",DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff"),"FileAttachments",attachment.FileName)
```